# How to make itertools combinations faster in python?

Tags: python

I tried a lot of things and still don't know why it doesn't work fast. How to I fix it?
It is a CodeWars 6 kyu task:

Given a set of elements (integers or string characters, characters only in RISC-V), where any element may occur more than once, return the number of subsets that do not contain a repeated element.

```
import itertools


def est_subsets(a):
    counter = 0

    a = list(set(a))

    p = itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.combinations(a, r)for r in range(1, len(a) + 1))

    for b in p:
        counter += 1

    return counter
```

Comment: The number of subsets of a set of size N is 2^N. This problem excludes the empty subset, so `return 2**len(set(a)) - 1` seems to solve the problem without enumerating all the subsets.

Comment: In general, these algorithm problems often require you to think of a solution that can be computed efficiently rather than write an inefficient solution and then try to make it fast. The "high performance tests" for this problem can give results as large as 1.2e30, which you're not going to want to wait for the computer to count one by one.

Comment: That was clear, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`itertools.combinations` needs to *generate* all the values. But you could just *compute* the number of values that *would be generated* directly, instead of generating them at all. Just use `math.comb` (added in 3.8), selecting the *length* of your input and you'll get the same results in a *tiny* fraction of the time.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the manual:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations

The number of items returned is n! / r! / (n-r)! when 0 <= r <= n or zero when r > n.

Which means that you can calculate the number or items it should return.